# How to categorize rows based on string in data.table column

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I have a data.table like this:

```
names <- c("Jones, Mr. Adam", "Sands, Mrs. Julie", "Andrews, Dr. Michael")
dat <- data.table(names=names)
```

I want create a title column based on the names column.  I can do it like this:

```
dat[str_detect(names, "Mrs."), title := "Mrs."]
dat[str_detect(names, "Mr."), title := "Mr."]
dat[str_detect(names, "Dr."), title := "Dr."]
```

but looking for a more efficient data.table method (tried lapply) using a vector (e.g. c("Mrs.","Mr.", "Dr.").

Comment: @Jaap; I want to use data.table and use a vector to create a title variable in data table. seems different to me than your link

Comment: following the linked Q&A: `dat[, title := str_extract(names, "(Mr|Mrs|Dr)\\.")]` works perfectly well imo

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub` to extract the substring from the 'names' column

```
dat[, title := sub("\\w+,\\s+(\\S+)\\s.*", "\\1", names)]
dat
#                 names title
#1:      Jones, Mr. Adam   Mr.
#2:    Sands, Mrs. Julie  Mrs.
#3: Andrews, Dr. Michael   Dr.
```

---

Or with `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
dat[, title := str_extract(names, "[A-Z][a-z]+\\.")]
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.table(names=names)
```